# What's the meaning of $C^1(R)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function $f(x)=(\max(-x,0))^2$ Show if $f(x)$ is in $C^1(R)$. I don't get what does $C^1(R)$.

Comment: [See this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes)

Comment: Maybe it stands for $C^1$($\mathbb{R}$) and it's a typing error...

Comment: Why did you not ask this to the person that gave you this problem? :-|

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez you're right I will send an email to Terry Tao, hope he answer me XD

Comment: Well, it is usually a good idea for people asking questions tot tell us where they got their problem from. Can you imagine why?

Comment: Not really, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

It means "continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$." $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ if $f$ is differentiable, and its derivative is continuous (on $\mathbb{R}$).

See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes) for more details, and the hierarchy of differentiability classes.

Answer (score 0):

$C^1(\mathbb{R})$ consists of the functions which are one time continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $f$ is continuous, differentiable, and its derivative is continuous.

Comment: @ClementC. my mistake